Why Ando operator is worse than Sobel operator when computing gradients in my case?
I am testing different gradient operators for 2D images. I have some differentiable function (let it be $f(x,y) = \sin(2x) + \cos(3y)$). I discretize this function (i.e make a 2D image of it) and then apply a gradient operator to the image to obtain an approximation $\hat{\nabla f}$ of the gradient of $f$. I compare $\hat{\nabla f}$ with the true gradient $\nabla f = (2\cos2x, -3sin3y)$ by summing point-wise errors of the approximation: $\sum_{ij} (\hat{\nabla f}_{ij} - \nabla f_{ij})^2$ This is the code of what I am doing: https://gist.github.com/shamazmazum/131d804d7f61df9a4d2562a23caa825e
Ando operator (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3193087_Consistent_gradient_operators) is designed to minimize a "power of inconsistency" in a sence that it minimizes $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y) - f_i(x,y))^2 + (\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,y) - f_j(x,y))^2$ where $g$ is some (unknown) differentiable function and $f_i$, $f_j$ are approximations for gradient components.
I would expect, that 5x5 Ando kernel would get better results in my test than Ando 3x3 and Sobel, but I get these results:
julia> sum(Compare.compare(500, Kernel.sobel))
118.24646607403068

julia> sum(Compare.compare(500, Kernel.ando3))
118.24646607403005

julia> sum(Compare.compare(500, Kernel.ando5))
268.72270170064337

Turns out Ando 5x5 kernel results in greater difference with the true gradient. Why is it so? What am I missing here?

Are you asking why a paper from 24 years ago that nobody has heard of doesn’t deliver on its promises? Or are you asking if your code matches the paper? If the latter, please post your code here (read minimal reproducible example first). Also, make sure you look at the derivatives you compute, maybe there’s an obvious edge effect or something like that.
